# Laravel - Calling model from controller looks for the wrong file name

Tags: php, laravel, model, controller, namespaces

I’m assuming this may be some convention I’m not understanding.

I have a model called Ingredient in the main App folder.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Ingredient extends Model
{
    protected $table = "ingredients";
}
```

Then I have a controller trying to call that app

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Config;
use App\Ingredient;

class IngredientController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return response()
            ->json([
                'status' => 'ok',
                'ingredients' => Ingredient::all()
            ]);
    }
}
```

Everything seems to be ok.  I get a 500 server error though:

```
include(C:\\Dev\\ScratchApi\\vendor\\composer\/..\/..\/app\/Ingredients.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

The file name of the model is `Ingredient.php`

Do I need to rename my file to Ingredients.php to meet a naming convention?  Or why is this trying to call a file name different from the class name I’m telling it to look for?

Comment: try to clear the cache and update the composer.

Comment: make use php artisan make:model ModelName -m. You need not to mention table name while using this command. Make sure you model name is singular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because of autoload cache. So, Run following command on your project root directory,

```
composer dumpautoload
```

Hope it works.

Comment: I think this is it.  In a few more minutes it will let me accept and answer.  I’ll mark this accepted.

Comment: @Jhorra Glad to help you bro.

Answer (score 1):

Add option "-o" when run dump autoload.

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
composer dump-autoload
```